# not able to reference children of children in D3 force layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to draw a force layout diagram using a fairly simple object structure. I am able to reach till the first level children but not able to see the second level children in the diagram. I am assuming I am probably missing a small piece. I am not seeing any console error either.

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/bzMhG/3/

[image: current state of diagram]

Here is the data

```
var inNodes = {
    "name": "My Name",
    "dept": "NYC",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "HTML",
            "level": "9",
            "size": 20,
            "chidlren": [
                {
                    "name": "HTML 5",
                    "level": "7",
                    "size": 15
                },
                {
                    "name": "HTML 4",
                    "level": "9",
                    "size": 20
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "name": "CSS",
            "level": "9",
            "size": 20,
            "chidlren": [
                {
                    "name": "CSS 2",
                    "level": "9",
                    "size": 20
                },
                {
                    "name": "CSS 3",
                    "level": "7",
                    "size": 15
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "name": "Java Script",
            "level": "8",
            "size": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "D3.js",
            "level": "6",
            "size": 10
        }
    ],
    "size": 20
};
return inNodes;
}
```

Comment: Just change `chidlren` to `children` in your code, then it works. I've got to admit that it took me a while before seeing it as well ;)

Comment: OMG!!!! This is nuts. I swear I probably spent 2 solid hours on this. LOL. Thanks for pointing that out. Amazing